# Nasm interrupt calls getting skipped and outputting multiple lines

Tags: assembly, x86, buffer, nasm, interrupt

After the first 2 calls are made, nothing bad happens but as soon as you press enter to choose the menu, it outputs the two prompts asking for user input instead of pausing at each prompt to enter the operands.

Why would the interrupts skip?

I am really confused right now.

```
SECTION .data

        AskForCalculationPrompt: db "Choose which operation you want", 0xA, "1. Addition", 0xA, "2.Subtraction", 0xA, "3. Multiplication", 0xA, "4. Division", 0x3
        AskForCalculationPromptln: equ $-AskForCalculationPrompt

        FirstOperandPrompt: db "Enter the first operand:", 0xA
        FirstOperandPromptln: equ $-FirstOperandPrompt

        SecondOperandPrompt: db "Enter the second operand:", 0xA
        SecondOperandPromptln: equ $-SecondOperandPrompt

        AnswerPrompt: db "The answer is: "
        AnswerPromptln: equ $-AnswerPrompt

        ErrorMsg: db "Wrong Choice made...insert correct choice"
        ErrorMsgln: equ $-ErrorMsg


SECTION .bss

        Choice: resb 1
        FirstOperand: resb 1
        SecondOperand: resb 1
        Answer: resb 1

SECTION .text

        ;Make interrupt to ask for a prompt ask for calculation prompt
        global _start

        _start:

        mov eax, 4 ;Specify sys_write call
        mov ebx, 1 ;Standard output
        mov ecx, AskForCalculationPrompt
        mov edx, AskForCalculationPromptln
        int 80h

        ;Make interrupt to read textfrom keyboard
        READ:

        mov eax, 3 ;Sys_read call
        mov ebx, 0 ;Standard input file descriptor 0
        mov ecx, Choice
        mov edx, 1
        int 80h

        ;Determine what we inserted

        ;Prompt for first operand
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, FirstOperandPrompt
        mov edx, FirstOperandPromptln
        int 80h

        ;Retrieve first operand input
        mov eax, 3
        mov ebx, 0
        mov ecx, FirstOperand
        mov ebx, 1
        int 80h

        ;Prompt for second operand
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, SecondOperandPrompt
        mov edx, SecondOperandPromptln
        int 80h

        ;Retrieve second operand input
        mov eax, 3
        mov ebx, 0
        mov ecx, SecondOperand
        mov edx, 1
        int 80h

        ;Load values retrieved into registers eax, ebx, ecx, for comparison and operation
        mov al, byte [Choice]
        mov bl, byte [FirstOperand]
        mov cl, byte [SecondOperand]


        JMP SWITCH
;*******************************************************************************
;SWITCH*************************************************************************
;*******************************************************************************
        SWITCH:

                cmp al, 0x31
                je ADDLABEL

                cmp al, 0x32
                je SUBTRACTLABEL

                cmp al, 0x33
                je MULTIPLICATIONLABEL

                cmp al, 0x34
                je DIVISIONLABEL

                JMP DEFAULTLABEL

        DEFAULTLABEL:

                mov eax, 4
                mov ebx, 1
                mov ecx, ErrorMsg
                mov edx, ErrorMsgln
                int 80h
                JMP READ


;*****************************************************************************
;OPERATIONS*******************************************************************
;*****************************************************************************

        ADDLABEL:
                mov al, cl
                add al, bl
                JMP DISPLAYOPERATION

        SUBTRACTLABEL:
                mov al, cl
                sub al, bl
                JMP DISPLAYOPERATION

        MULTIPLICATIONLABEL:
                mov al, cl
                mul cl
                JMP DISPLAYOPERATION

        DIVISIONLABEL:
                mov al, cl
                div cl
                JMP DISPLAYOPERATION

;*****************************************************************************
;DISPLAYOPERATION*************************************************************
;*****************************************************************************

        DISPLAYOPERATION:

                mov [Answer], eax
                mov eax, 4
                mov ebx, 1
                mov ecx, Answer
                mov edx, 1
                int 80h

                mov eax, 1
                mov ebx, 0
                int 80h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you've run into is the fact that `sys_read` (from stdin) doesn't return until it sees a linefeed (the "enter" key). Only the one character you're looking for goes into your buffer (Choice), the linefeed stays in the OS's buffer (call it the "keyboard buffer"). When the next `sys_read` comes along, it reads that linefeed into your next buffer (FirstOperand)... and carries on... Hilarity ensues!

The easy way to fix it would be to make those buffers `resb 2` and make `edx` 2, and trust the user to enter only one key and then "enter"... each time... Then studiously ignore the second byte in each buffer.

A better way might be to "flush the buffer" - the OS's keyboard buffer, not the buffer you've just read into. When `sys_read` returns, the number read is in `eax`. If it's less than `edx`, you should be good (it won't be, in this case). If it's equal (it shouldn't be greater), check to see if the last character is that linefeed. If it is, you're good. If not, there's more cruft in the OS's buffer (which will screw up your next `sys_read`!). Read into a "dummy" buffer (in `.bss` or on the stack), a byte at a time, until you find that linefeed - `cmp byte [dummybuf], 0Ah` or so. Then you're ready to continue...

Such are the joys of raw sys_call programming. :)

You don't ask, but `mov [Answer], eax` could be asking for trouble. This will write to your one-byte buffer... and the three bytes after it! There's nothing after it, and it isn't butted up against memory you don't "own", so it won't cause a problem right now, but it's a "bug waiting to happen". Either use `al` (should work here), or make Answer `resd` so it'll fit all of `eax`

This isn't going to give you the answer you expect. You need to subtract '0' (or 30h or 48) from each operand before you do arithmetic on 'em, and then add '0' back to the answer before you print it. With nore than one digit, it's even worse! Get the interrupts working as intended first.

Comment: Yes i should move al instead of eax. And for the subtract '0' i figured that out when my outputs were smiley faces.

Comment: Do you reccommend any books on how to correctly design/structure assembly programs? Cause i know the basic functions/registers but i dont know how to correctly put them together. Im using assembly language step by step which is great but it didnt go deep enough to my taste.